# Chaining decorator in python does not give result

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to understand chaining decorators in the  below python code.

```
'''
Chaining decorator example, should not work 
'''

import datetime
def getArgs(func):
    def inner():
        print("Doing ",func.__name__)
        a = int(input("enter A :- "))
        b = int(input("enter B :- "))
        return func(a,b)
    return inner

def logTime(func):
    def inner():
        print("\n")
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        func()
    return inner

@logTime
@getArgs
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

@logTime
@getArgs
def minus(a,b):
    return a-b

print(add())
print(minus())
```

The output  I get is :-

```
2022-04-22 00:53:08.067977
Doing  add
enter A :- 1
enter B :- 1
None <----------- why None ?


2022-04-22 00:53:08.807530
Doing  minus
enter A :- 1
enter B :- 1
None <----------- why None ?
```

Why is the output "None" ? I experimented with `return func()` in `logTime's inner` & I could get the correct output.

What I want to understand is why `return` is required in the `logTime's inner` ?

Comment: Because otherwise the `logTime` decorator returns a function that doesn't return the result of the decorated function

Comment: For the same reason it's required in `getArgs`' `inner`. A better question is why do you think it's required in one and not the other?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo as per my understanding, getArgs gives required args to add/minus but logtime only logs time there is no to & fro of args required. Maybe I did not get this right....

Comment: @IainShelvington can you please elaborate, i think i am getting some sense to what you are saying

Comment: @penta when you use a decorator, it is called after the decorated function is defined and the decorated function's name is replaced with the result of the decorator. You essentially replace the decorated function with the inner function, so when you call `add` you are really calling `inner` and if `inner` doesn't return anything you get None

Comment: Because like *any other function*, if you don't return anything, then `inner` will implicitly return `None`

Answer (score 2):

Decorators are just syntax sugar, what it does is just `add = getArgs(add)`, which returns `inner()` function object. Then by calling `add()` you call `inner()` and if it does not return then result is obviously `None`.

You may think that chaining does something different but no, it just does the same

```
add = getArgs(add)  # will return inner() of getArgs
add = logTime(add)  # will return inner() of logTime
```

Now when you call `add()` it calls `inner()` of `logTime`, that `inner()` calls `inner()` of `getArgs` and that `inner()` calls initial `add()`. There is no magic